# how to insert html content into DB

Tags: php, mysql

how to insert hmtl content into DB, below is the code i am trying but not successful. Can any body help me how it can be done-:

```
<?php    
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("send_mailer",$connect);
$msg= <<<HTMK
<html>
<body>
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center'>
<tr>
<td align='center'><img src='http://d32vlg867bsa1v.cloudfront.net/z/prod/w/2/b/home-images/Sept/27092013/tops-l.jpg' /></td></tr>
<tr>
<td align='center'>
<img src='http://d32vlg867bsa1v.cloudfront.net/z/prod/w/2/b/home-images/Sept/19092013/row3-01-l.jpg' />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center'>
<img src='http://d32vlg867bsa1v.cloudfront.net/z/prod/w/2/b/home-images/Sept/27092013/shoes-l.jpg' />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
HTMK;
$query_1="INSERT INTO content (htmk) values ($msg)";
$result=mysql_query($query_1);
?>
DB table structure-:
1   htmk    varchar(5000)
```

Comment: It looks good, could you paste your database structure?

Comment: You should use the mysqli_ functions or PDO. The ones you're using are old-style and won't be around much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's missing " or ' around string value in your query.

since your $msg contains special chars, it should be escaped manually or using mysql_real_escape_string function.

`$query_1="INSERT INTO content (htmk) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($msg)."')";`

By the way, mysql_ functions are deprecated, why not to use PDO?

Answer (score 1):

Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module.  You will not have to do all that encoding hoohah that the other answers have suggested.  See this question: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)  The question is about SQL injection, but the principles of using parametrized queries are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlentities function in PHP to encode all tags into their HTML equivalents.
Then you can insert the result string in a varchar-based or text-based column.

Here you can find out how:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting HTML in database try applying  [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on the string `$msg` to put into the DB, and then, when pulling it back out, use [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php). Should work.